# почему пишет ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Введите ваш вес: '

Tags: python

Не совсем понимаю как работает input в python(недавно начал изучать), как сделать так чтобы значения
вводились с клавиатуры и верно считались? код:

```
gender = input(str('Введите ваш пол:'))
weight = input(float('Введите ваш вес: '))
height = input(float('Введите ваш рост: '))
def find_ideal_weight(gender,height):
    ideal_weight = ''
    if gender == 'М':
        ideal_weight = (height-100)*0.9
    elif gender == 'Ж':
        ideal_weight = (height-100)*0.85
    return ideal_weight
print('Ваш текущий вес: ',weight)
print('Ваш идеальный вес:',find_ideal_weight(gender,height))
```

причем если делать все с заранее введенными числами, то все получается хорошо, а с input - нет

Comment: `weight = float(input('Введите ваш вес: '))`

Comment: спасибо! работает, а не подскажите почему float()после input?

Comment: Нет такого метода, который можно было бы использовать для непосредственного приема ввода как числа с плавающей запятой, но входная строка может быть преобразована в число с плавающей запятой с помощью функции float (), которая принимает строку или число и возвращает значение с плавающей запятой. Таким образом, мы используем функцию input () для чтения ввода и преобразования его в число с плавающей запятой с помощью функции float ().